# Stopping time sigma-fields

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

Let $(F_n)$ be a discrete Filtration and $S_n,S$ (not necessarily finite) stopping times with $S_n\uparrow S$ (increasing convergence).

Is it true that the associated sigma-fields satisfy $F_{S_n}\uparrow F_S$
(meaning $F_S=\sigma(\bigcup_nF_{S_n}):=G$)?

Since $S\leq T$ implies $F_S\subseteq F_T$ we have $G\subseteq F_S$ and conversley I can prove that for $A\in F_S$ we have $A\cap[S<\infty]\in G$
but cannot prove $A\cap[S=\infty]\in G$.

Comment: Can you write out how you proved $A \cap [S < \infty] \in G$?  It might suggest something for someone.

Comment: Oh, I see how to do that case.  Let $B_n = \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \bigcap_{m \ge n} \{S_m = k\}$ be the event that the sequence of stopping times stabilizes past $S_n$.  Then for any $k$ we have$A \cap B_n \cap \{S_n = k\} = A \cap B_n \cap \{S=k\}$.  Now $A \cap \{S=k\} \in F_k$ and $B_n \cap \{S=k\} = \bigcap_{m \ge n} \{S_m = k\} \in F_k$.  So $A \cap B_n \cap \{S_n = k\} \in F_k$ thus $A \cap B_n \in F_{S_n} \subset G$.  Now $\{S < \infty\} = \bigcup_n B_n$ so $A \cap \{S < \infty\} = \bigcup_n A \cap B_n \in G$.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I am writing myself some notes on the topic and would attach a short pdf if I could find out how to do this.

Comment: You can't attach the PDF here, but you could post it somewhere else and add a link, or just paste the text here (the $\LaTeX$ math might need slight editing).

Comment: The claim is true if the $F_n$ are finite (modulo null sets) and $S=\infty$. To see this we claim that
$$
\forall m\exists k: P(T_k<m)=0.
$$
Otherwise there exists an $m$ such that $P(T_k<m)>0$, for all $k$.
The sets $[T_k<m]$ are all in the finite family $F_m$. From this it follows
that infinitely many of these sets are the same, i.e. there exists a set
$A\in F_m$ with $P(A)>0$ such that $[T_k<m]=A$, for infinitely many $k$.
But this contradicts $T_k\uparrow S=\infty$.

Comment: continued from previous remark: we can now use induction to construct a strictly increasing sequence $k_m\uparrow\infty$ such that $P(T_{k_m}<m)=0$. Then
$F_{T_{k_m}}\supseteq F_m$ and the claim follows from this. I believe that it is not true in general, but now we know where not to look for a counterexample.